# Win32 Audio API endpointVolume interface returning wrong channel count

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, volume

I have a sound application that uses the win32 [Audio API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The problem is that when I call:

```
  endpointVolume->getChannelCount(&count);
```

it returns  2 channels (but 6 channels are enabled in windows). I know they all work because I get output from the speakers and I have also check the peak values with:

```
  IAudioMeterInformation->getMeteringChannelCount()
```

and I get 6 channels and the peak values are bigger then 0. So there is output.. Does anybody know why this happens? Is it a bug or a badly coded driver? Can I get the volume values any other way?

Comment: yes it is, thats why i'm get 6 peak channels and only 2 volume channels

Comment: What soundcard and driver are you using? Have you checked the manufacturer site for an update?

Comment: yes i've installed the latest drivers. I'm using realtek HD audio driver (6.0.1.6482)

Comment: What are you using to play out the audio?

Comment: the application doesn't play audio it only listens to what other audio applications are sending to the sound card.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [link on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv-SE/windowspro-audiodevelopment/thread/8bf33c9c-72c3-4333-8171-db4b497fbee6) with a person describing a similar problem, and in summary, here is what you should do:

1. Check to see if the device's volume is coming from a driver or APO using QueryHardwareSupport.
2. Inform Microsoft about the bug (even though they probably won't do anything about it).
3. Play around with the api your using to see if you can fix it (random function calls, etc...).
4. Assuming that doesn't work, use an alternate api to get the number of channels.
5. If all else fails, buy a different soundcard, because that one obviously ain't workin' right.

Comment: tried 1-3 with no luck. the problem with buying a new sound card is that i can't say that to the end user (Your sound card driver isn't properly supported, please go buy a new one :P)

Answer (score 0):

If you prepare your own buffers to play out audio, you can get the volume yourself.  If you want, I'll paste some code to do so...

Comment: the application doesn't play audio, it only checks what other applications are outputing (on a global scale) and does some logic according to that. And that is why i need to get the volume values per channel.

Comment: Maybe the best way would be for you to hook into audio output and calculate peaks yourself, if you can't rely on API...

Comment: the problem is not the peaks but the volumes, i get all peak channels correctly but i get only 2 volume channels (instead of 6!).